# Use different titles for moderncv resume and cover letter

Tags: templates, moderncv

I am using [this](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/moderncv-cv-and-cover-letter) beautiful template. There is only one thing that I don't like in it but unfortunately I am not very good in LaTeX to change it on my own. What's is more, the code involved in this template is a lot, and therefore it is almost imposable to construct a working example here. So, I rely on your own will to provide this improvement (and I promise that I will send this patch to the guy who maintains this site so as other people get benefit from that).

So, my problem is that the template uses the same title (on top of the page) for both the CV and the Cover Letter (which is also included on the tex file). What I want is be able to define separately the titles for these two sections ("Curriculum Vitae and Cover Letter say).

Could you please help me out with this patch?

**FYI:** I am using the "banking" theme

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a `\title{Covering Letter}` after the CV part (and after the `\clearpage`) and before the `\makelettertitle` will do what you are after.

EDIT: Re icons

The icons are from fonts. there is a `\moderncvicons{}` setting which currently has three possible values: `awesome`, `marvosym` and `letter`. `awesome` is the default but will only work if you are using `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX`, otherwise it drops back to `marvosym`.

There are `.sty` file which describe the different options `moderncvicons<iconstylename>.sty`. if you look in these you can see the command used  for each icons (here is the relevant part of the `awesome` style:

```
\renewcommand*{\addresssymbol}       {}
\renewcommand*{\mobilephonesymbol}   {{\Large\faMobilePhone}~}
\renewcommand*{\fixedphonesymbol}    {\faPhone~}
\renewcommand*{\faxphonesymbol}      {\faPrint~}              % alternative: \faFileAlt
\renewcommand*{\emailsymbol}         {\faEnvelope~}           % alternative: \faInbox
\renewcommand*{\homepagesymbol}      {\faGlobe~}              % alternative: \faHome
\renewcommand*{\linkedinsocialsymbol}{\faLinkedinSign~}       % alternative: \faLinkedin
\renewcommand*{\twittersocialsymbol} {\faTwitter~}
\renewcommand*{\githubsocialsymbol}  {\faGithub~}
```

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks a lot! And one more tricky question if you don't mind: How could I add my own icons on the top of the page (i.e. regarding the contact details)?